# React initial input value is empty and not taking the state or the prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I used for a long time Vue, and I'm passing to React right now. To exercise I'm trying to convert some basic Vue components to React.
I had a simple code on Vue as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello {{message}}</h1>
    <input v-model:value="message" placeholder="Type a name"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
       return { message: 'World!' };
    }
  }
</script>
```

And as equivalent for React I have done the following:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state={message: 'World!'};
  changeValue = e => { this.setState({message: e.target.value}); };
  render() {
    return (<div>
        <h1>Hello {this.state.message}</h1>
        <input value={this.message} placeholder="Type a name" onChange={this.changeValue}/>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

It worked as charm, and the binding is perfect exactly like the Vue `v-model`, so the reactivity is perfect, except one thing: The initial value of the input isn't the message state which is `'world!'` but it's just empty, showing the placeholder; Thus, I thaught it was just taking the default value of the input.
I tried to work with a computed property by creating a getter and thaught it might work, in vain. Now I'm sure that I can handle this with calling the `onChange` handler of the input after the component got mounted in the method cycle `componentDidMount`, but I feel like it's not a good practice to do this each time I have to work with an input or, worse, with a form.
Can you please tell me:

- why is this happening accordingly to the React cycles logic,
- and what's the best way to handle it?

Comment: Instead of `value={this.messageValue}` use `value={this.state.message}`.

Comment: Indeed. It was the error. I didn't pay attention to it, and when I worked in the handler or the life cycle methods, I used this.state.message, so yeah, this was the error. Thanks. Just put a reply and I'll choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `value={this.state.message}` instead of `value={this.message}`. Accessing your state variables is done via `this.state`.